# How to use php to store and display any visitor's input

Tags: php, mysql, dhtml

I want to create a very simple site, but unfortunately my php skills are weak. Basically, when a user shows up, I want to have a page with text and a blinking cursor (I can probably figure the cursor part out myself, but feel free to suggest). When a user types, I want it to show the text as they type, and when they hit enter (or click something/whatever), the text just typed will be sent to a database and then the page will update with that new text, for anybody else to see. The cursor will then be blinking on the next line down. So basically it's like a really simple wiki, where anyone can add anything, but nobody can ever remove what has been typed before. No logging in or anything. Can someone suggest the best way to go about this? I assume it will require a php call to the database to display the initial page, then another php request to send data, then another php request to display the new page. I just don't know the details. Thanks so much!

Bonus question 1: How can the page be updated dynamically, so if A sends text while B is typing, B sees the text A sent on B's page immediately?

Bonus question 2: What sorts of issues might arise if this database grows extremely large (say, millions of words), and how might I address these up front? If necessary, I could show only a small chunk of the (text-only) database on any given page, then have pagination.

Comment: There *a lot* of php tutorials out there. Pick one and get learning PHP!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one page, you don't need a database. All you need to do is save a text file on the server (use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) and related functions) that only gets appended to. If you have multiple pages, then a simple `id (INTEGER), filetext (LARGEBLOB)`. (Note `largeblob` has a [limit of 2^32 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)).

For the user's browser part, you'll need to use Javascript and AJAX to inform the server of any updates. Just get in touch with a PHP script that (1) accepts the input and (2) appends it to a file.

> Bonus question 1: How can the page be updated dynamically, so if A sends text while B is typing, B sees the text A sent on B's page immediately?

Also use the AJAX call to fetch new content (e.g. if you assign line numbers, then the browser just tells the script the last line it read, and the script returns all new lines past that point).

> I assume it will require a php call to the database to display the initial page, then another php request to send data, then another php request to display the new page.

Pretty much. But only send the last 50 lines or so of the file when the browser visits it. You don't want to crash the browser.

> Bonus question 2: What sorts of issues might arise if this database grows extremely large (say, millions of words), and how might I address these up front? If necessary, I could show only a small chunk of the (text-only) database on any given page, then have pagination.

Think in terms of bytes, not words, and you'll likely run into performance issues. You could cap file sizes or split up the storage into multiple files at a certain size so you don't have to scan pass content that will rarely be fetched.